# Problema con el modulo upper-case

Tags: nodejs

Hola estoy iniciando con Node.js. Estoy tratando de correr el siguiente código (que tome desde un tutorial)

```
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('upper-case');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(uc("Hello World!"));
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error.

```
TypeError: uc is not a function
```

Creo que puede ser un error desde el momento en que instale upper-case pues cuando lo instalo con

```
npm install upper-case
```

obtengo el siguiente menseje

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file directory "C:/Users/RTC/pakage.json"
```

Entonces tengo las siguientes dudas

1. Es un problema de instalación de upper-case, o un problema en el códgio que intento correr.
2. Como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Primero debes crear el archivo `package.json` con `npm init`, después instalas el módulo con `npm i upper-case` y ya podrías usarlo

Comment: Gracias desaparecio el warning con con este paso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El warning sólo te dice que no existe el archivo `package.json`, eso no debe darte problemas, ya depende de tí si lo inicializas o no.

El error que tienes es porque estás usando mal la función, el código es:

```
res.write(uc.upperCase("Hello World!"));
```

Y por qué no usar la función nativa `toUpperCase`:

```
res.write("Hello World!".toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono con uc.upperCase! Supongo que el ejemplo trataba de mostrar la incluisión de modulos por eso no usar la función nativa, que por cierto no la conocia!